# how to convert object(SimpleXMLElement) to string

Tags: php, parsing, dom, xpath

I am using xpath to parse text from a webpage but it returns it as an object how can i return this as a string.

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($source);
$xml = simplexml_import_dom($dom);
libxml_use_internal_errors(FALSE);
$username = $xml->xpath("//span[@class='user']");
```

var_dump of the $username array:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (2) { ["@attributes"]=> array(1) { ["class"]=> string(4) "user" } [0]=> string(11) "bubblebubble1210" }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
list(, $node) = $username;

var_dump($node);
// object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (1) { [0]=> string(11) "bubblebubble1210" }
```

`$node` will still be an object above, but you can cast it explicitly with `(string)` or use `echo` which will cast it implicitly.

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/M8pR5MAT).

Comment: i used that code and it returns this string(1) "r" but shouldn't it return more than more character?

Comment: Yes, are you doing a `foreach()` (or subscripting) on the resulting string accidentally?

Comment: how would i use those code to parse external html page rather than a string

Comment: @jennifer You can use [`simplexml_load_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$username->asXML();` to get the full string of that particular SimpleXMLElement object.